# Block with the same function as page of Taxonomy term view

Tags: taxonomy-terms

Is there any way to replicate as block which displays all nodes associated with the end of the url, like page view ( Taxonomy term view -A view to emulate Drupal core's handling of taxonomy/term.)  but in a block. 
Example in url news/term1 the block should be able to show all nodes with the term term1.

Thank

Answer (score 3):

- Set up a new view of type "node"
- Give the view a "block" display (not a page)
- In the "advanced" section of the view (on the right) create a relationship to "taxonomy term"
- you can set up a "contextual filter" based on "taxonomy term".
- The trick to making this work with a block is to select the "Provide default value" option and select "raw value from url" "path component 3". This will send in the id of the parent term from the url (works even though your term is aliased).
- Go to admin->blocks and put that block in the "footer" region; set it to only appear at the url taxonomy/term/* (this will work even though your term is aliased).

Comment: Works great, thank you for answering. Thank you very much.